# регулярные выражения лишние результаты

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, python-3.x, парсер

Собственно говоря появляются лишние результаты поиска, нужно только доставать ссылки заданного формата из текста.

---

```
import re
hl_pattern=r'hl=[a-z]{2}(\-[a-z]{2})?'
http_pattern=r'((http|https):\/\/)?(www\.)?'
login_pattern=r'[a-zA-Z0-9_\.]*[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9_\.]*'
image_hash_pattern=r'[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]*[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]*'
taken_by_pattern=r'taken-by=[a-zA-Z0-9_\.]*[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9_\.]*'
account_link_pattern=r'\b({0}instagram.com/{1}(\/\?{2})?\/?)\b'.format(http_pattern,login_pattern,hl_pattern)
image_link_pattern=r'\b({0}instagram.com/p/{1}(\/\?{2})?(\/\?{3})?(&{3})?\/?)\b'.format(http_pattern,image_hash_pattern,taken_by_pattern,hl_pattern)

def MainLogic(message):
    acc_reg=re.compile(account_link_pattern)
    im_reg=re.compile(image_link_pattern)
    account_links=re.findall(acc_reg,message)
    image_links=re.findall(im_reg,message)
    return account_links+image_links

MainLogic('http://instagram.com/mikaev , https://www.instagram.com/p/BXvBcb7jB3x/')
```

---

Результат:

```
[('http://instagram.com/mikaev', 'http://', 'http', '', '', ''),
 ('https://www.instagram.com/p/', 'https://', 'https', 'www.', '', ''),
 ('https://www.instagram.com/p/BXvBcb7jB3x',
  'https://',
  'https',
  'www.',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '')]
```

А нужны только 3 ссылки.

---

Помогите пожалуйста, спасибо большое!

Comment: Автор, опиши свою задачу. Ты сейчас написал кучу абсолютно неподдерживаемых регулярок и сам не понимаешь, как они работают. При этом в твоём случае достаточно `str.index("instagram.com/")` и поиск от этой позиции до конца ссылки. Зачем здесь регулярки?

Comment: какие 3 ссылки нужны?

Answer (score 0):

Используйте группы без обратной связи `(?:шаблон)`

```
import re
hl_pattern=r'hl=[a-z]{2}(?:\-[a-z]{2})?'
http_pattern=r'(?:(?:http|https):\/\/)?(?:www\.)?'
login_pattern=r'[a-zA-Z0-9_\.]*[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9_\.]*'
image_hash_pattern=r'[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]*[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]*'
taken_by_pattern=r'taken-by=[a-zA-Z0-9_\.]*[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9_\.]*'
account_link_pattern=r'\b({0}instagram.com/{1}(?:\/\?{2})?\/?)\b'.format(http_pattern,login_pattern,hl_pattern)
image_link_pattern=r'\b({0}instagram.com/p/{1}(?:\/\?{2})?(?:\/\?{3})?(?:&{3})?\/?)\b'.format(http_pattern,image_hash_pattern,taken_by_pattern,hl_pattern)

def MainLogic(message):
    acc_reg=re.compile(account_link_pattern)
    im_reg=re.compile(image_link_pattern)
    account_links=re.findall(acc_reg,message)
    image_links=re.findall(im_reg,message)
    return account_links+image_links

t = MainLogic('http://instagram.com/mikaev , https://www.instagram.com/p/BXvBcb7jB3x/')
print('\n'.join(str(value) for value in t))
```

Выводит

```
http://instagram.com/mikaev
https://www.instagram.com/p/
https://www.instagram.com/p/BXvBcb7jB3x
```

Тест https://repl.it/KLvj/0